# React order is lost when updating Safari only

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a list of toggle button example.

```
Option one ()

Option two ()

Option three ()
```

I can toggle each one independently example

```
Option one (selected)

Option two ()

Option three (selected)
```

This works in Chrome and Firefox correctly, but in safari the order gets lost.
if I select "option one" it re-renders like this.

```
Option two ()

Option three ()

Option one (selected)
```

It moves it to the bottom of the list. My understanding is that react respects the order in which the objects are render.

This is the `OptionMenuComponent` This renders a list of options there can be a list of `OptionMenuComponent` that also loses order when updating the state. Again this happens only in Safari.

```
class OptionMenuComponent extends React.Component {

  selectedOption(key) {
    let updatedState = {selectedState: this.props.data[key].isSelected !== true}
    this.props.updateOptionState(this.props.queryKey, key, updatedState)
  }

  generateOptions() {
    var results = []
    for (var key in this.props.data) {
      var option = this.props.data[key]
      let color = {backgroundColor: option.hasOwnProperty("color") ? option.color : "rgb(240, 240, 240)"}
      results.push(
        <div class="multiple-option-button" key={key} onClick={this.selectedOption.bind(this, option.key)}>
          <div class={option.isSelected ? "multiple-option-dot-selected" : "multiple-option-dot"} style={color}></div>
          <div class="multiple-option-text">{option.displayText}</div>
        </div>
       )
    }
    return results
  }

render() {
  return (
    <div>
     <div class="optionsMenu-section-title">{this.props.title}</div>
     {this.generateOptions()}
    </div>
  );
}
```

the options objects are pass in as props. When the the user click the callback is triggered to update the state in the parent object.

This is this how the `OptionMenuComponent` is rendered in the parent.

```
 <div class="white_content" style={{display: this.state.showFilters ? "block" : "none"}}>{this.generateFilters()}</div>
```

and this is the func that it calls

```
generateFilters() {
    var results = []
    results.push(<div class="filter_options_title">Filters</div>)
    for (var filterKey in this.state.data) {
      if (Object.keys(this.state.data[filterKey].options).length > 0) {
        results.push(
          <OptionMneu key={filterKey} title={this.state.data[filterKey].displayText}
          data={this.state.data[filterKey].options}
          updateOptionState={this.updateOptionState}
          queryKey={filterKey}>
          </OptionMneu>
        )
      }
    }
    return results
  }
```

Comment: We can't really help you debug this issue without seeing the code of th component where this is happening. Could you share that?

Comment: I thought this might be a common thing. Updated with code.